# Can waves other than light also form Poisson's bright spots? For example, water waves, sound waves, earthquake waves, etc

Tags: waves

Can waves other than light also form Poisson's bright spots? For example, water waves, sound waves, earthquake waves.
Moreover, what kind of wave will not form Poisson's bright spots theoretically?